# How to manage MySQL database transactions using python?

Tags: python, mysql

How to connect transaction database in python?

I try to create database in MySQL and cannot connect in python. I need the transaction page should be run.

Comment: There seem to be a number of questions here. Can you pick one for us to help with?  Transactions are tied to your session if that helps at all.

Comment: Have you installed the connector as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/)?